# Passing callback as a parameter to function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I trying to write a generic function which takes the function and number of milliseconds as argument and it sets it to `setTimeout` function. I tried: like

```
$("#Delay").click(function() {
    delayCallBack(someFunction(a, b), 100);
});
```

In `delayCallBack` function:

```
function delayCallBack(event, time) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        event();
    }, time);
};
```

But this is not working and throwing me JavaScript error. Can someone please help me with the right way of doing this?

Comment: Probably not going to help that you are actually calling `someFunction(a,b)` when you think you are sending a reference to it... what you are actually doing it sending the **result** of it

Comment: In what scope are a and b defined?

Comment: And what is the exact error you are getting?

Comment: @JørgenFogh : Error I get in firebug  "Error: useless setTimeout call (missing quotes around argument?)".  scope is within function. So delayCallBack cant have a,b. It has to be passed as argument.

Comment: @Senthilnathan: It *is* possible to pass a and b along, as I have detailed in my answer. The code becomes pretty complicated though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace

```
$("#Delay").click(function() {delayCallBack(someFunction(a,b), 100);});
```

With

```
$("#Delay").click(function() {delayCallBack(function(){someFunction(a,b)}, 100);});
```

The first line executes `someFunction(a,b)` instead of what the second line does, passing a reference to a function to execute.

Answer (score 2):

`()` invokes a function, so you call the function rather than pass it. Pass the function like normal variable:

```
$("#Delay").click(function() {
    delayCallBack(someFunction, 100);
});
```

---

Your function can be cleaned up a little... then again it's not that different from just calling `setTimeout` directly..

```
function delayCallBack(callback, time) {
    setTimeout(callback, time);
}
```

---

To pass the arguments `a` and `b`, you can create a new function out of your existing function that partially applies `a` and `b`, then pass it:

```
$("#Delay").click(function() {
    delayCallBack(someFunction.bind(null, a, b), 100);
});
```

More of [`.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind). Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Pd5JZ/2/

Comment: @JørgenFogh not sure what they are, the OP could have gotten `ReferenceError` from the `a` and `b`, so I left them out. But since he didn't say what error he has, it's unclear.

Answer (score 0):

This question has a surprisingly tricky answer in JavaScript, since you pass in the values `a` and `b`. Consider Gerard Sexton's solution

```
$("#Delay").click(function() {
    delayCallBack(function() {
                      someFunction(a,b);
                  }, 100);
});
```

What that code does depends on where `a` and `b` are defined and what happens to them after the handler is bound. Suppose we put it in context:

```
$(function () {
    var a, b;
    a = b = 5;
    $("#Delay").click(function() {
        delayCallBack(function() {
                          someFunction(a,b);
                      }, 100);
    });
    a = b = 7;
}
```

Then `someFunction` will be called with `a=b=7`, not `a=b=5`. If you want the first values, you have to copy the values when you bind the handler. Like so:

```
$(function () {
    var a, b;

    function bind(a, b) {
        $("#Delay").click(function() {
            delayCallBack(function() {
                              someFunction(a,b);
                          }, 100);
        });
    }

    a = b = 5;
    bind(a, b);
    a = b = 7;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting the same error : setTimeout call (missing quotes around argument?).
Gerard Sexton explanation is right.

The correct code should be

```
$("#Delay").click(function() {delayCallBack(function(){someFunction(a,b)}, 100);});
```